React Native Expo App: SplashScreen Hiding Too Quickly and Onboarding Route Flashing
I'm developing a React Native app using Expo and expo-router, and I'm encountering two issues with my app's initialization and routing:

The splash screen is hiding too quickly, even when I set a timeout.
The onboarding screen briefly flashes before redirecting to the auth layout, even though I'm using a protected route.

App Structure
I have a root layout that loads fonts and checks the onboarding status:
import { BottomSheetModalProvider } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import { useOnboardingStore } from "../store/onboard";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const { checkOnboardingStatus } = useOnboardingStore();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    // Font loading code...
  });

  useEffect(() => {
   const prepareApp = async () => {
  if (loaded) {
    await checkOnboardingStatus();
    SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }
};
    prepareApp();
  }, [loaded]);

  // Render code...
}

I'm using a Zustand store to manage the onboarding state:
export const useOnboardingStore = create<OnboardingState>((set) => ({
hasCompletedOnboarding: null,
isLoading: true,
completeOnboarding: async () => {
// Implementation...
},
checkOnboardingStatus: async () => {
  // Implementation...
},
}));

export function useOnboardingRoute() {
// Route protection logic...
}

And here's my onboarding layout:
const OnBoardLayout = () => {
const { hasCompletedOnboarding } = useOnboardingStore();

if (hasCompletedOnboarding) {
  return <Redirect href={"/(auth)/"} />;
}

return (
  <Stack>
    <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  </Stack>
);
};

Issues

Splash Screen: The splash screen is hiding almost immediately, even though I'm using SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() and only calling SplashScreen.hideAsync() after fonts are loaded and onboarding status is checked.
Onboarding Route: When opening the app, the onboarding screen briefly appears (for about a second) before redirecting to the auth layout, even though I'm checking the onboarding status and using a Redirect component in the OnBoardLayout.

Questions

How can I ensure the splash screen stays visible until the app is fully ready (fonts loaded and initial route determined)?
What's causing the brief flash of the onboarding screen, and how can I prevent it to ensure a smooth transition to the correct initial route?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
